# Gradient Mask is applied multiple times in reused prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a tableview, with a customer UITableViewCell class - this is created as a prototype cell in Storyboard/Builder.

Because my cell is linked to the Storyboard prototype, I reference it as follows (cellIdentifier matches the ID on the prototype cell):

```
EventsListTableViewCell *cell = (EventsListTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

As such, the cell is always initialised and ready (I can't use "if (cell == nil{...} ")

This is fine, however I want to add a gradient layer to my cell, which I'm doing within cellForRowAtIndex:

```
gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientMask.frame = cell.eventImage.layer.bounds;

gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.2);
gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
gradientMask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.0f] CGColor],

                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],nil];
[cell.eventImage.layer insertSublayer:gradientMask atIndex:0];
```

The issue here, is that the gradientMask gets applied for each re-use of the cell, so when I scroll down it gets darker and darker

I realise I need to only apply this gradientMask once, when the cell is first created, however I'm not sure where to call this code, as I never 'init' the cell (this is handled by the storyboard)

I do have a custom class for this cell, but it only contains properties and no methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways of achieving this:

**1- Property in UITableViewCell subclass**

Create a property in the EventsListTableViewCell class which will hold a reference to the gradientMask:

```
@interface EventsListTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *gradientMask;

@end
```

And then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if (!cell.gradientMask) {
    gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientMask.frame = cell.eventImage.layer.bounds;

    gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.2);
    gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    gradientMask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.0f] CGColor],

                           (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],nil];
    [cell.eventImage.layer insertSublayer:gradientMask atIndex:0];
    cell.gradientMask = gradientMask;
}
```

This will make sure that the gradientMask is initialized only once.

**2- [name property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/name) of `CALayer`**

This way, you don't need to create a property and everything can be handled in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method itself.

```
BOOL gradientFound = NO;

for (CALayer *layer in cell.eventImage.layer.sublayers)
{
    if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"gradientLayer"])
    {
        gradientFound = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if (!gradientFound)
{
    gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientMask.frame = cell.eventImage.layer.bounds;
    gradientMask.name = @"gradientLayer";               //Set the name
    gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.2);
    gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    gradientMask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.0f] CGColor],

                           (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],nil];
    [cell.eventImage.layer insertSublayer:gradientMask atIndex:0];

}
```

**3- Declaring the gradienLayer in the UITableViewCell subclass itself**

This is the cleanest way as it also isolates the code related to the cell within it's class. You can initialize the cell in the `awakeFromNib` method.

```
@implementation EventsListTableViewCell
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradientMask;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientMask.frame = cell.eventImage.layer.bounds;

    gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.2);
    gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    gradientMask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.0f] CGColor],

                           (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],nil];
    [self.eventImage.layer insertSublayer:gradientMask atIndex:0];
}

@end
```

Comment: great that works! I just started playing with adding this code to the EventsListTableViewCell  'initWithCoder' method - which seems to be called, but the gradient doesnt show. Just for my knowledge, would that be a better 'cleaner' solution?

Comment: Absolutely! instead of the `initWithCoder:` method, use the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks! Just one edit - on the final method above, I think cell.* should be self.*

Comment: Follow up question added: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214364/gradient-layer-over-imageview-reuse

Comment: @Ben Answered that question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding this layer yourself out of storyboard file, this layer will net be deleted during the `cellReuse` cycle. You have to do it manually.
I usually create a subclass for the cell and override `prepareForReuse` method, where I remove all the custom views and layers I have added there. This way everything will work smoothly.
And don't forget to add your subviews to cell's `contentView` property only.